# Site stopped when jQuery ajax load big element

Tags: jquery

I used jQuery load() instead of iframe for make no refresh site.

But site stopped all when load big element(content section) for a fleeting moment.

BGM player, scroll, click and all stopped.

I want load not stopped.

Comment: getting any console error ..

Comment: A web page is a single threaded application, so if a very long task is assigned to it then all other operations including user interactions in the page will be blocked till the task is completed. So the solution will be is to redesign the solution so that there is no huge task performed at once without a break

Comment: to which specific browser?

Comment: no error. load is perfectly. I used Chrome newest version.

Comment: can I dom changing using multi thread?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to make a SPA (single page application). There are many mature frameworks in the market that help you achieve this in a very elegant way. Angular.js by google and Ember.js are a few examples. They have full templating and MVC support in built.

You should go ahead and use one of these and your page will be more responsive and manageable even with big content changes on the fly.

Comment: For what you are doing currently please make sure that your ajax call is not sync. Set async = false..!!

Comment: My code is very simple. only using load(). I don't require MVC.